# why search input field will be missing inside the mobile browser views

Tags: 2013, search, mobile

I am working on a team site collection and I enabled the mobile browser view feature for my site:

[image]

Currently I have got more mobile friendly views for my pages, but seems the search field is not appearing on the mobile views. Do I need to enable extra features for search to appear on mobile views?